# A script to warn about apache2 certificates about to expire?

Tags: apache2, certificates

In Redhat there is a script called `certwatch` that warns when apache certificates about to expire.  Is there anything similar for Ubuntu?  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

It seems [`certwatch`](https://github.com/notroj/certwatch) has also been split from RHEL, and is also available as a stand-alone script.

In addition, there is a script called [`ssl-cert-check`](https://github.com/Matty9191/ssl-cert-check) that also can check expiry of certificates.

Usage:

```
$ ssl-cert-check -s {SERVER_NAME} -p {PORT}
```

The script is [described here](https://prefetch.net/articles/checkcertificate.html).

Finally, you can also use `openssl` directly to get the expiry date and time:

```
$ echo | openssl s_client -servername {SERVER_NAME} -connect {SERVER_NAME}:{PORT} | openssl x509 -noout -dates
```

Comment: ssl-cert-check is just I was looking for, because it has a an email warning feature.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(although Artur's answer probably helps us not recreate the wheel)

`openssl` has a "check date" flags... easily usable in a cron job (or script)

**On local certs:** (I have a cert with the filename pulled192.168.13.5.pem)

`openssl x509 -in pulled192.168.13.5.pem -noout -enddate` - outputs expiration

> notAfter=Jul 23 17:56:34 2025 GMT

The **-checkend** flag accepts your date (*think number of days*) input in seconds.
`openssl x509 -in pulled192.168.13.5.pem -noout -checkend 9999` - outputs whether expiring or not within your input timeframe(in seconds)

> Certificate will not expire

`openssl x509 -in pulled192.168.13.5.pem -noout -enddate -checkend 9999` - combine both flags

> notAfter=Jul 23 17:56:34 2025 GMT
> Certificate will not expire

`openssl x509 -in pulled192.168.13.5.pem -noout -enddate -checkend 99999999999`

> notAfter=Jul 23 17:56:34 2025 GMT
> Certificate will expire

**Or pulled remotely:**

`openssl s_client -connect 192.168.13.3:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout  -enddate -checkend 9999`

> notAfter=Mar 20 18:54:38 2023 GMT
> Certificate will not expire

`openssl s_client -connect 192.168.13.3:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout  -enddate -checkend 99999999999`

> notAfter=Mar 20 18:54:38 2023 GMT
> Certificate will expire

**To answer the question: (to "script" it....)**

On command line this works: (I have another local cert that expires in less than 10 days)

`openssl x509 -in signed.domain.pem -checkend 864000 -noout || notify-send "Cert will expire soon"` - will send display a custom notification with notify-send if cert is expiring under 10 days (864000 seconds)

To, additionally, display the number of days we are testing for, in the notification.
Here we would change the secs value instead of directly changing the -checkend value, when we want to increase/decrease testing the days until cert expiration.
`secs=864000; let days=$secs/60/60/24; openssl x509 -in signed.domain.pem -checkend $secs -noout || notify-send "Cert will expire soon (less than $days days)"`

Answer (score 1):

I grew tired of typing **openssl** commands, so I now use (and maintain) the wrapper scripts named **https-*** listed [here](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Erp/webhosting-bin.html).

Comment: Nice script collection!  Maybe you could include the source of `https-expiry` in your answer for completeness sake?

Comment: I'm not sure it will improve the answer: it depends on the other scripts and there is too much boilerplate in them to ready make that worthwhile. I plan to join them together into a single script, which I might post here.